# Zabbix: zabbix_sender and passive checks (based on zabbix_agent) do not work simultaneously

Tags: zabbix

We have a zabbix-server with several hosts, configured via web interface of zabbix. On each host there are several data items with the type "Zabbix agent", i.e. data items gather in the passive mode, with a certain periodicity on the basis of requests from the server to hosts with the agent, set on them. Data are gathered correctly.

There is a need to get optional data from one of such hosts by zabbix_sender.

The new data item with the type "Zabbix trapper" was configured via web interface of zabbix. If I call zabbix_sender at the host, which should send this data (zabbix_sender.exe -z 'address of zabbix server' -s 'host name' -p 'port of zabbix server' -k 'item key' - o 'new item value' -vv) - it works only when passive checks from the server to the agent (configured earlier) aren't executed. If I call zabbix_sender at the time of such check, I get the error "Connection timeout occured", and after check completion zabbix_sender begins to work again (data are sended to the server correctly).

The full text of error: zabbix_sender.exe [6988]: DEBUG: send value error: cannot connect to [[X.X.X.X]:10051]: A connection timeout occurred. Sending failed.

And so, this is my question: can zabbix_sender and passive checks (based on zabbix_agent) work at the same time, simultaneously? And if it is possible, what should we do for this purpose?

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: This should not be an issue at all. How do you know this is related to the passive items, shouldn't those execute very quickly? Using the Zabbix internal monitoring, what is the busy rate for the Zabbix trapper processes?

Comment: I see that it is related to the passive checks. Passive checks are configured to begin every 5 minutes. For example, next passive check will begin at 15:00. Before this moment (at 14:48, 14:49, etc.) zabbix_sender works well and returns results. At 15:00 it stops to work and returns error "Connection timeout occured". At 15:01 it begins to work, and at 15:05 it will stop working again.

Comment: Using the Zabbix internal monitoring, I configured 2 checks: zabbix[process,trapper,avg,busy] and zabbix[process,poller,avg,busy]. The results of the first check: min - 0%; max - 0,06%. The results of the second check: min - 1,9%; max - 8,29%. I have only one trapper now, and it does not work automatically (with some script), I call zabbix_sender from cmd.

Comment: Why do you have only one trapper process? Have you had it like this from the very beginning? Most likely that is the cause. I'd suggest going back to 5 trappers.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant that I have one item with type "Zabbix trapper". I did not change the deafult number of start trappers in zabbix_server.conf (# Default:
# StartTrappers=5).

Comment: I gave you the wrong statistics earlier. It is right only for the first part of today. For the last 7 days the results are: for trappers min 0%, max 8,49%; for pollers min 0,61%, max 100%. Is it nesessary to increase Start Pollers in zabbix_server.conf?

Comment: I tried to increase the value of "StartPollers" from 5 to 50, but it didn't help to resolve my problem.

Comment: Pollers should not affect the zabbix_sender operation. Please link the built-in Zabbix server template to your Zabbix server host, it will provide many more internal items. Please check whether any of the caches gets full, or any other process gets to 100% busy rate.

Comment: There are no problems with caches: Zabbix configuration cache - 84.83% of free space, Zabbix history index cache - 99.65%, Zabbix history write cache - 100%, Zabbix trend write cache - 96.7%, Zabbix value cache - 98.09%.

Comment: The statisctics for last 7 days: 1) Values processed by Zabbix server per second: min - 13.41, max - 39.28; 2) Zabbix busy alerter processes: min - 0%, max - 100%; 3) Zabbix busy configuration syncer processes: min - 0%, max - 100%; 4) Zabbix busy db watchdog processes: min - 0%; max - 16.98%; 5) Zabbix busy discoverer processes: min - 0%; max - 100%; 6) Zabbix busy escalator processes: min - 0%; max - 100%; 7) Zabbix busy history syncer processes: min - 0.05%, max - 75.85%;

Comment: 8) Zabbix busy housekeeper processes: min - 0%, max - 100%; 9) Zabbix busy http poller processes: min - 0%; max - 100%; 10) Zabbix busy icmp pinger processes: min - 0%; max - 0.1 %; 11) Zabbix busy poller processes: min - 0.08%; max - 93.93%; 12) Zabbix busy proxy poller processes: min - 0%; max - 100%; 13) Zabbix busy self-monitoring processes: min - 0%; max - 0.05%; 14) Zabbix busy timer processes: min - 0%; max - 100%; 15) Zabbix busy trapper processes: min - 0%, max - 34.5%; 16) Zabbix busy unreachable poller processes: min - 8.67%, max - 100%;

Comment: 17) Zabbix queue: min - 0, max - 448; 18) Zabbix queue over 10m: min = max = 0; 18) Zabbix value cache hits: min - 7.04, max = 591.06; 19) Zabbix value cache misses: min - 0, max - 11.79; 20) Zabbix value cache operating mode: min = max = 0. Can you explain, which of these checks can be connected to the sender's work?

Comment: We have already increased the values of StartPollers, StartTrappers, StartPollersUnreachable and StartDiscoverers - it made better the statistics of Zabbix busy poller processes, Zabbix busy unreachable poller processes and Zabbix busy discoverer processes. But what can resolve our problem with sender ?

Comment: I have also noticed in zabbix_sender.log, that there are a lot of such requests from our hosts to zabbix_server: trapper got '{"request":"active checks","host":"X","port":XXXXX}'. These requests begin every 2 minutes by default. We have no active agents now (only passive), but the parameter "ServerActive" is configured at some hosts in zabbix_agentd.conf. Could it lead to our problem with sender?

Comment: The trapper process busy rate should be the most important number here, and it does not seem to indicate an overload situation. If you don't use active checks, comment out the ServerActive parameter - it just results in extra network connections and log entries. Do you have any firewalls or other devices that could limit the connection rate - either on the server or on the network?

Comment: Zabbix_sender sends requests to the port 10051 on zabbix server. This port is available. The command "netstat -ntpl" returns these results:                 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                tcp6       0      0 :::10050                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::10051                :::*                    LISTEN      -
It returns these results even when the sender does not work.

Comment: I deactivated the items, that were gathered from my host in the passive mode. After it zabbix_sender began to work well. Any other thoughts about it?

Comment: I don't see how passive/active items could be related here, unless you have a really messy network. What network devices do you have between that host and Zabbix server?

Comment: Also, are you passing Zabbix server IP or DNS name to the zabbix_sender? If the DNS name, does the problem go away if you use IP? If so, do you have a DNS name specified in the 'Server' parameter on the agent?

Comment: We are passing Zabbix server IP to the zabbix_sender. In the zabbix_agentd.conf file the parameter 'Server' is IP too. But we don't use this agent's config, we call sender in this way: zabbix_sender.exe -z 'address of zabbix server' -s 'host name' -p 'port of zabbix server' -k 'item key' - o 'new item value' -vv

Comment: And this problem is not only on one host. I have already got it on two different hosts. Other hosts I didn't check.

Comment: This would likely need more debugging then, which seems offtopic here. I'd suggest bringing this topic up on the Zabbix IRC channel.

Comment: Ok, we'll try to do it. Nevertheless, thank you!